# scala coding to do the Huffman decoding, but wrong result

Tags: scala, huffman-code

```
 abstract class CodeTree
  case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
  case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree


type Bit = Int
 def decode(tree: CodeTree, bits: List[Bit]): List[Char] = {
 if(!bits.isEmpty) {
     bits.head match {

  case 0 => tree match {
    case Fork(l, r, _, _) => decode(l, bits.tail)
    case Leaf(_, _) =>  chars(tree) ::: decode(frenchCode, bits.tail)

  }
  case 1 => tree match {
    case Fork(l, r, _, _) => decode(r, bits.tail)
    case Leaf(_, _) =>  chars(tree) ::: decode(frenchCode, bits.tail)

  }
}
}
else Nil
 }

  val frenchCode: CodeTree = Fork(Fork(Fork(Leaf('s',121895),Fork(Leaf('d',56269),Fork(Fork(Fork(Leaf('x',5928),Leaf('j',8351),List('x','j'),14279),Leaf('f',16351),List('x','j','f'),30630),Fork(Fork(Fork(Fork(Leaf('z',2093),Fork(Leaf('k',745),Leaf('w',1747),List('k','w'),2492),List('z','k','w'),4585),Leaf('y',4725),List('z','k','w','y'),9310),Leaf('h',11298),List('z','k','w','y','h'),20608),Leaf('q',20889),List('z','k','w','y','h','q'),41497),List('x','j','f','z','k','w','y','h','q'),72127),List('d','x','j','f','z','k','w','y','h','q'),128396),List('s','d','x','j','f','z','k','w','y','h','q'),250291),Fork(Fork(Leaf('o',82762),Leaf('l',83668),List('o','l'),166430),Fork(Fork(Leaf('m',45521),Leaf('p',46335),List('m','p'),91856),Leaf('u',96785),List('m','p','u'),188641),List('o','l','m','p','u'),355071),List('s','d','x','j','f','z','k','w','y','h','q','o','l','m','p','u'),605362),Fork(Fork(Fork(Leaf('r',100500),Fork(Leaf('c',50003),Fork(Leaf('v',24975),Fork(Leaf('g',13288),Leaf('b',13822),List('g','b'),27110),List('v','g','b'),52085),List('c','v','g','b'),102088),List('r','c','v','g','b'),202588),Fork(Leaf('n',108812),Leaf('t',111103),List('n','t'),219915),List('r','c','v','g','b','n','t'),422503),Fork(Leaf('e',225947),Fork(Leaf('i',115465),Leaf('a',117110),List('i','a'),232575),List('e','i','a'),458522),List('r','c','v','g','b','n','t','e','i','a'),881025),List('s','d','x','j','f','z','k','w','y','h','q','o','l','m','p','u','r','c','v','g','b','n','t','e','i','a'),1486387)
  val secret: List[Bit] = List(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)
  def decodedSecret: List[Char] = decode(frenchCode, secret)ode here
```

I am new to scala, and learning the pattern matching now, I want to do the huffman decoding, now I could get a list, but it is the wrong answer, hope someone could find the mistake.

Comment: I am pretty sure nobody is going to read through the giant manually-specified code tree and list of bits to find an error if one exists there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You do not want to consume a bit when you hit a leaf. A character of the leaf should also be added if there is no bit in your code.
2. In the decode methode you do not want to reference frenchCode, but code instead that is given as a parameter.
3. You can access the char of the leaf via pattern matching, i.e. case Leaf(codeChar, _) => ...

Btw. your code will be way cleaner if you start matching on the tree. Only if it matches to a fork you look at the head of your bit list.

Hope that helps. ;)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot,that works! the code should be like this: case Leaf(_, _) =>  chars(tree) ::: decode(frenchCode, bits).  Your first suggestion is helpful. I know it is a kind of hard code here use the frenchcode, but since I recursively call the decode, so when matching a leaf, the tree is already a leaf and could not transferred to  do the next character decoding...

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you should make sure the function gets parameterized the frenchCode or else you cannot use your decode function for other Huffman trees.

Comment: Plus one on not consuming a bit when hitting a leaf